# What's the earliest attested use of "there're"?

Tags: word-usage, history

I've tried searching for *there're* online, but I haven't been able to find any good information. Most sites assume I'm looking for ***they**'re*. [Wiktionary claims *there're* was coined by Bob Dylan](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/there're), but I find this highly unlikely.

I tried [Google's n-gram page for *there're*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there%27re&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthere%20%27re%3B%2Cc0), but when I checked some of the early results in Google books, they didn't mean *there are*, many instances being mismatched by the software.

What's the earliest attested use of *there're* where it's intended to mean *there are*?

Comment: I think the Wiktionary entry is just claiming that that particular quotation is attributed to Bob Dylan.

Answer (score 2):

The earliest example I found is from **1632**:

> There're more hammers beating in my braine
>   Then euer toucht *Vulcans* Anuile, more Ideaes
>   Then Attomes, Embrions innumerable,
>   Growing to perfect shape; and now 'tis good.
>   <sub>[The iron age contayning the rape of Hellen: the siege of Troy: the combate between Hector and Aiax: Hector and Troilus slayne by Achilles: Achilles slaine by Paris: Aiax and Vlisses contend for the armour of Achilles: the death of Aiax, &c.](https://books.google.com/books?id=n9M4AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA369)</sub>